# How many units of mist energy do you actually regenerate per day?

Tags: spiral-knights

I tried to build a very basic spreadsheet for keeping track of energy regeneration in Spiral Knights under the assumption that you regen 100 units of energy per day as the game itself says.

However, energy seems to recharge to a rate actually faster than that. Has anybody run the numbers on how fast energy actually recharges? Does energy recharge faster if you're not logged in?

Comment: For reference the numbers I crunched seem to give a speed of 110 while logged off and 102 while logged in, but it's all very inaccurate given how infrequent and unnoticeable energy changes are.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a feature that no longer exists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [wiki article](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Energy) indicates that it does indeed recharge at a higher rate (100 in 22 hours).

That's one unit every 13.2 minutes, so in 24 hours you'd gain 109.09 units.

Answer (score -2):

Every 24 hours = a day get your mist all generated to 100.