# How can I get around the Raid Boss time limit?

Tags: borderlands-2

Borderlands pulled a pretty jerk move and made the new "Raid Bosses", Master Gee and Hyperious The Invincible(s), work on a **24 hour timer**. Since they drop *absolute crap*, ~10 crystals each time when you need >100 to buy a weapon, it's clearly ideal to cheat the clock.

How can I get around the raid boss time limit? I'm on PC generally playing Co-op. Can I just change my PC's clock ahead a day? Does the multiplayer host have to change *their* clock alone, or everyone? Or is it server based so we have to play offline? Additionally, can Console players just change their clock to get out of it as well?

Comment: Have you tried with your local clock on your PC ? It should work because single player don't require internet. So Gearbox should not now the change.

Comment: @Warface yeah, I'm 95% sure that works...won't answer my own question until I can test for realsies though

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it Daily Raid boss time limits were removed in the 8/29/13 Borderlands 2 patch.


Comment: It does, we've covered this before.  The question is outdated, because said "feature" the OP wants to get around no longer exists, rendering the question useless

Comment: see: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24870/how-many-units-of-mist-energy-do-you-actually-regenerate-per-day and http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/948/18916

Comment: See, more recent decsion: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7235/what-do-we-do-with-historic-questions-that-no-longer-make-sense

Comment: @fbueckert I'm voting to reopen as per that meta post. Anyone playing an older version of the game will find this question useful. In fact, a [quick search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=borderlands+2+play+with+older+version&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=ogQkUoiWG7KhsQSs8YH4DQ#q=borderlands+2+version+downgrade&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial) reveals several resources about downgrading to a previous version of the game.

Answer (score 7):

Always change the clock *to the past, not the future*. The lockout is for 24 hours from the last time the system marked you as defeating the boss. If that time is in 2014, you won't be able to play the boss again with your clock set to normal until after that date (e.g., for Xbox, any time your console is online).

Comment: +1 for recommending using those 24-hour periods that you've already missed, rather than booking ahead. :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply changing the system clock to 24 hours ahead (just change the day without changing the time) is enough to allow you to re-fight both Master Gee and Hyperious. There's no server-side checking so it doesn't matter if your online.

Note that for co-op, *all* players have to have their timers reset, you can't start the fight if someone in your party still has the countdown active. It flashes a message stating such if you try to shoot the boss (to start the fight), they'll take no damage and won't turn aggressive, nor will you be locked in with them. If you're farming these bosses as a group just have everyone change their clock at once.

Here's instructions for how to change your system clock in [Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-vista/Set-the-clock), [Xbox](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906661) and [PS3](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/settings/date.html).

Comment: That's what I've thought.

Comment: For Windows, do you have to exit the game?  Or just change your clock?

Comment: @fbueckert good question, I'll test that out. I failed to actually kill him solo so I didn't get to test reseting it...

Answer (score 1):

Ben is correct.  Another thing that can be done if trying to farm is the other non hosts players either alt + F4, or sign out fo the respectivive servies right before either boss dies.  Or turn power off.  Just make sure it doesn't save for the 3 non hosts.  Then rejoin after he is dead.  This won't give credit for boss but will allow a group of 4 to farm the boss.  Also an assassin, zero, with the bore ability can damage hyperius fully throughout the fight.  The shield counts as an enemy so in effect dealing double damage, even more if you can line up the bots.

So you can kill hyperius fairly quickly without worrying bout the bots.

Comment: If players quit and rejoin like this they won't be able to help in the fight though, will they? Even with the Baby Maker trick I found  him fairly hard to solo, but very very easy with 3 people

Answer (score 1):

Not to worry, a recent update has fixed this:

From the [patch notes](http://support.gearboxsoftware.com/entries/22126761--PC-Update-Hot-Fix-Information%5D):

> - Disabled the daily lockout for raid bosses

Feel free to destroy Hyperius or whomever as many times as you'd like!

Comment: Answers like this is what confuses me about this site... since the old methods are outdated, does that mean those answers are invalid and this answer should be considered correct?

Comment: Well since there's no daily lockout anymore, this question is then technically "invalid". As such, I'll vote to close

Answer (score 0):

You will need 2 storage devices and 2 characters who can use claptraps stash for this to work and it doesnt really matter what level the second character is.

Just go place of the boss u want to farm, when there save and quit make a backup copy. If the boss doesnt drop anything you want, sign out then sign back in, kill again and repeat until you get something you want.

When you got what you want, take to sanctuary and put in claptraps stash, then save and quit, choose another character and retrieve the loot from claptraps stash with the other character.

Then you can re copy the copy you made earlier and farm again for more loot knowing the other character has the loot you already gained the previous fight, therefore not losing the loot and being able to farm indefinitely.

When you finished farming you can grab the loot from your other character to give back to your main character by using claptraps stash again.

NOTE: I play xbox 360 version and copy between my hard drive and my built in hard drive. This can be done with a USB stick aswell. I guess it would work on other platforms though.